# Api working on curl and not on GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, rest, symfony, curl, guzzle

I'm trying to connect to the Talentlink Api. I'm able to do it on curl but I can't connect using GuzzleHttp. I'm using Guzzle through the m6web/guzzle-http-bundle on Symfony. My code is below. Does anybody have an idea?

CURL

```
        $headers = [
                    'username: XXXXX',
                    'password: XXXXX'
        ];

        $body = '{
                  "searchCriteriaSorting": {
                    "categoryListsSorting": "LABEL",
                    "customLovsSorting": "ORDER",
                    "standardLovsSorting": "ORDER"
                  }
                }';

        $tuCurl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api3.lumesse-talenthub.com/CareerPortal/REST/FoAdvert/advertisement-by-id?api_key=XXXXXX&lang=FR&postingTargetId=1");
        curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $head = curl_exec($tuCurl);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($tuCurl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($tuCurl);
```

GUZZLE

```
        $headers = [
            'username' => 'XXXXXX',
            'password' => 'XXXXXX'
        ];

        try {
            $response = $client->request('GET',
                'https://api3.lumesse-talenthub.com/CareerPortal/REST/FoAdvert/advertisement-by-id?api_key=XXXXX&lang=FR&postingTargetId=1',
                array(
                    'debug'     =>  true,
                    $headers
                ));
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            die((string)$e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
        }
```

On Guzzle, I keep getting a page with a login form as if I wasn't connected. However, the status is always 200 so it's difficult to debug.

**SOLUTION**

It was a problem with the array I was sending. It should be like this wit the 'header' key:

```
$response = $client->request('GET',
            'https://api3.lumesse-talenthub.com/CareerPortal/REST/FoAdvert/advertisement-by-id?api_key=XXXX&lang=FR&postingTargetId=1',
            [
                'headers' => $headers,
                //'debug' => true
            ]);
```

Comment: Is the post getting redirected at some point ?

Comment: Shouldn't the array passed into the `request` method be a single level array? You've set your `$headers` array as a value in the array instead of merging the arrays.

Comment: I.e. the second arg should probably simply be `$headers`, and if you want debug, add it to the `$headers` array beforehand for simplicity.

Comment: @JonStirling, I tried what you said but it wasn't the problem... I saw this way of debugging Guzzle somewhere and I was trying it. it helps me because I can see the request I send but I don't understand why it can't connect yet.

Comment: @user3489615 I'm not sure you understood so I'll just double check since I'm not specifically talking about the debug part. My main point is that I don't believe you should be passing a multi-dimensional array as the second arg of the `request` method, which is what your example code is doing.

Comment: @PedroLobito, it doesn't seem to be redirected. I just get the form as I wasn't connected.

Comment: @JonStirling, yes I think I got it. I'm doing like this now: $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api3.lumesse-talenthub.com/CareerPortal/REST/FoAdvert/advertisement-by-id?api_key=XXXXX&lang=FR&postingTargetId=1', array(
                    'debug'     =>  true,
                    'username' => XXXX',
                    'password' => 'XXXX',
                ));

Comment: @JonStirling thanks so much for your help! It was exactly the problem with array! I just posted the solution above.